# How i can use Mocha and Chai to make an Async Test for Endpoints created by Node?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, mocha.js, chai

```
describe('Notifications API', ()=>{

    /*Getting All Notification*/
    describe('getNotifications', ()=>{
      it('it should GET all the notifications', async () => {
          const result = await chai.request(app).get('/getNotifications');
          result.should.have.status(200);
        });
    });
})
```

Comment: I got this error msg "Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves)"

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to not use `async/await`:

```
describe('Notifications API', () => {
    /*Getting All Notification*/
    describe('getNotifications', () => {
        it('it should GET all the notifications', (done) => {
            chai.request(app)
                .get('/getNotifications').then(result => {
                    result.should.have.status(200);
                    done()
                }).catch(e => {
                    done(e)
                })
        });
    });

})
```

Also I've tested your code using `await` and it works properly.

```
it('Prueba', async () => {
    const result = await chai.request('https://stackoverflow.com').get('/');
    return result.should.have.status(200);
  })
```

Ensure your API returns data in less than 2 seconds and add a `return` (although it's not strictly neccessary).

And as a tip: Don't call your path `getNotifications` it has more sense to be only `/notifications`. Verb you use says you want to do, not the path.

You are using `get` verb into petition so is redundat to add `get` into path.